# ¿Se dice "a ser posible" o "de ser posible"?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, expresiones, preposiciones

Leyendo una [web de bebés](http://espanol.babycenter.com/l25009795/7-men%25C3%25BAs-para-ni%25C3%25B1os-peque%25C3%25B1os-fotos#ixzz4PQQ3Ucm6) traducida en México me encontré con un menú:

> Una galleta salada (**de ser posible**, integral) y 1/4 de taza de queso (bajo en grasas) es una merienda deliciosa y entretenida que puedes compartir con tu bebé.

Como veis, además de lo delicioso de la comida me sorprendió el uso de la expresión *de ser posible*. Esta quiere decir "preferiblemente", pero yo siempre la he usado con la preposición *a*: *a ser posible*.

Mirando en Google Ngram me doy cuenta que [ambas coexisten](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+ser+posible%2Cde+ser+posible&year_start=1800&year_end=2015&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20ser%20posible%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cde%20ser%20posible%3B%2Cc0) y se alternan el liderato en cuanto a cuál usar (deberían filtrarse usos tangenciales, eso sí):

> [image]

Por lo que me pregunto: ¿existe una forma aceptada sobre la otra para esta expresión? ¿Tiene diferencias regionales? Nótese que en España es donde reconozco el uso de *a ser posible* mientras que la web creo que está traducida en México (no encuentro referencias en el sitio, pero por el tipo de español que usan lo juraría).

Comment: CORDE: "a ser posible" (222 casos) vs "de ser posible" (81 casos). CREA: "a ser posible" (450 casos) vs "de ser posible" (177 casos).

Comment: Nunca tuve ninguna duda de que se dijera de dos maneras diferentes. SIempre he usado "de ser posible". Interesante saber que clase de respuestas traerá esta pregunta. +1

Comment: *a ser posible* parece ser la forma innovadora, y con la respuesta de Carlos la innovación ocurrió en España

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Según queda registrado en el DRAE, por un lado tenemos:

> **[a](http://dle.rae.es/?id=003Ov93)**
>
> Del lat. *ad*.
>
> 12. prep. Ante infinitivo, en expresiones de sentido condicional, equivale a la conjunción *si* con indicativo o subjuntivo. *A decir verdad.*

Luego "a ser posible" equivale a "si es posible". Por otro lado tenemos:

> **[de](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BtFYznp)**
>
> Del lat. *de*.
>
> 12. prep. U. seguida de infinitivo con valor condicional. *De saberlo antes, habría venido.*

Luego "de ser posible" también significa "si es posible". Luego las dos opciones son igualmente válidas. Sobre su uso, si buscamos las expresiones en el CREA y obtenemos sus estadísticas, tenemos:

```
                País    Porcentaje de uso
-----------------------------------------
a ser posible   ESPAÑA    88.51%
                MÉXICO    2.87%
                CHILE     1.91%
                CUBA      1.19%
                ARGENTINA 0.95%
-----------------------------------------
de ser posible  ARGENTINA 28.48%
                ESPAÑA    25.58%
                MÉXICO    20.93%
                PERÚ      5.81%
                VENEZUELA 3.48%
```

Por tanto, "a ser posible" es de uso mayoritario en España, mientras que "de ser posible" es mucho más usada en Hispanoamérica, aunque también tiene su nicho en España.

Answer (score 0):

Yo entiendo las dos formas:

- *A ser posible*, en mi opinión, indica deseo de que algo se haga o sea de una manera determinada.
- *De ser posible*, significaría que no se tiene conocimiento de que algo sea posible y que, en caso de que resulte que sí es posible, entonces...

Comment: ¿Podrías aportar algún ejemplo? A mí me sonaba haberlo oído indistintamente